# Flask Lazy loding with waitress

Tags: python, flask, waitress

im was working with my flask app on my development server, but now i want to move that same application to a production enviroment. The thing is that when i was running that same application with flask run, i got the lazy loading message so i move to waitress in order to avoid this behaviour. When i use waitress the message dissapears but the behaviour is the same. The app is slow at the first request and then works properly.

Bellow you can find part of my code :

```
import flask
import io
import string
import time
import os
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import load_model
import prepare_image
from flask_cors import CORS
from waitress import serve
from paste.translogger import TransLogger

app = Flask(__name__)
#control archivo mayor a 16 mb
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 4096 * 4096
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])

blablabla

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve(TransLogger(app, setup_console_handler=False),port=5000)
```

Thanks in advance

when the app is served with weitress the lazy loading mode doesnt seem to disappear.

Comment: i try to use gevent too and even load my prediction model on the first lines of my main.py but i get the same behaviour. After some minutes the applications load the model again and this is why the first request takes more time. Once the model is loaded the api works properly.  Any ideas?